# Why does POSIX demand that system(3) ignores SIGINT and SIGQUIT?

Tags: linux, shell, signals, posix

The [POSIX spec says](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html)

> The system() function shall ignore the SIGINT and SIGQUIT signals, and shall block the SIGCHLD signal, while waiting for the command to terminate. If this might cause the application to miss a signal that would have killed it, then the application should examine the return value from system() and take whatever action is appropriate to the application if the command terminated due to receipt of a signal.

This means that a program that starts a long-running sub-process will have `SIGINT` and `SIGQUIT` blocked for a long time. Here is a test program compiled on my Ubuntu 18.10 laptop:

```
$ cat > test_system.c <<< EOF
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    system("sleep 86400");  // Sleep for 24 hours
}
EOF
$ gcc test_system.c -o test_system
```

If I start this test program running in the background...

```
$ ./test_system &
[1] 7489
```

..Then I can see that `SIGINT`(2) and `SIGQUIT`(3) are marked as ignored in the bitmask.

```
$ ps -H -o pid,pgrp,cmd,ignored
  PID  PGRP CMD                                  IGNORED
 6956  6956 -bash                       0000000000380004
 7489  7489   ./test_system             0000000000000006
 7491  7489     sh -c sleep 86400       0000000000000000
 7492  7489       sleep 86400           0000000000000000
```

Trying to kill test_system with `SIGINT` has no effect..

```
$ kill -SIGINT 7489
```

.. But sending `SIGINT` to the process group does kill it (this is expected, it means that every process in the process group receives the signal - sleep will exit and system will return).

```
   $ kill -SIGINT -7489
   [1]+  Done                    ./test_system
```

## Questions

1. What is the purpose of having `SIGINT` and `SIGQUIT` ignored since the process can still be killed via the process group (that's what happens when you do  a `^C` in the terminal).
2. Bonus question: Why does POSIX demand that `SIGCHLD` should be blocked?
3. **Update** If `SIGINT` and `SIGQUIT` are ignored to ensure we don't leave children behind, then why is there no handling for `SIGTERM` - it's the default signal sent by kill!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SIGINT` and `SIGQUIT` are terminal generated signals. By default, they're sent to the foreground process group when you press `Ctrl+C` or `Ctrl+\` respectively.

I believe the idea for ignoring them while running a child via `system` is that the terminal should be as if it was temporarily owned by the child and `Ctrl+C` or `Ctrl+\` should temporarily only affect the child and its descendants, not the parent.

`SIGCHLD` is blocked so that `system`'s the `SIGCHLD` caused by the child terminating won't trigger a `SIGCHLD` handler if you have one, because such a `SIGCHLD` handler might reap the child started by `system` before `system` reaps it.

Comment: Ok, so it's not about managing lifetimes of the child processes, but about making the terminal work consistent with user expectations. That sounds reasonable.